# Spring-Kafka producer throughput is way less than pure java producer

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and writing a simple async producer with the below settings:

```
producer config key : acks  and value is : 1
producer config key : max.in.flight.requests.per.connection  and value is : 5
producer config key : compression.type  and value is : lz4
producer config key : linger.ms  and value is : 10
producer config key : batch.size  and value is : 64000
producer config key : bufferMemory  and value is : 67108864
producer config key : key.serializer  and value is : class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
producer config key : value.serializer  and value is : class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

I can produce upto 20k messages per second with apache java client but with spring-kafka, its coming to not more tha 3k messages per second

What could be wrong here?

Comment: The `KafkaTemplate` should not add much (measurable) overhead it's simply a wrapper for the `KafkaProducer`; please provide a small, complete, sample app that exhibits this behavior and I'll take a look to see what's wrong. Make sure you have not set `autoFlush`  to true, however, since that would probably explain it.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the response. I'm setting autoFlush to false and I'll try to create a sample project and share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I see no significant difference; nothing like what you are seeing...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63308954Application {

    private static final int COUNT = 1_000_000;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63308954Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63308954-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63308954-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor exec() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor exec) {
        return args -> {
            StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
            Producer<String, String> producer = template.getProducerFactory().createProducer();
            String payload = new String(new byte[1024]);
            exec.submit(() -> {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("so63308954-1", payload);
                Future<RecordMetadata> future1 = null;
                watch.start("native");
                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    future1 = producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
                    });
                }
                System.out.println(future1.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                watch.stop();
                return null;
            }).get();
            template.getProducerFactory().reset();
            exec.submit(() -> {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("so63308954-2", payload);
                ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = null;
                template.send(record); // create a new producer outside of the timer
                watch.start("spring");
                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    future = template.send(record);
                }
                System.out.println(future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
                watch.stop();
                return null;
            }).get();
            System.out.println(watch.prettyPrint());
            TaskInfo[] taskInfo = watch.getTaskInfo();
            for (TaskInfo info : taskInfo) {
                System.out.println(info.getTaskName() + " rate: " + COUNT / info.getTimeSeconds() + " / sec");
            }
            producer.close();
        };
    }

}
```

Results:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 4454736954 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
2205227969  050%  native
2249508985  050%  spring

native rate: 453467.856410994 / sec
spring rate: 444541.4562325031 / sec
```

Comment: I see no significant difference with this test; I do see some minor variations when running it, but sometimes the native takes a bit longer than Spring and sometimes the other way around, but not a big difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i did miss something in my code which is causing the huge difference and i found it now and it's doing good.